# Dash: Output('text2','children') TypeError: 'Output' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, data-science, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I want to create a div in which i want to call values of sales this year and previous year by selecting the year(in slider) in dashboard but it gives me a error.
Can i output multiple values?
what i am doing wrong ?

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e06RT.png)

```
 html.Div([
        html.Div(id = 'text1'),
        html.Div(id = 'text2'),
        
        
    ],className='create_container2  three columns')



@app.callback(Output('text1', 'children'),
          Output('text2','children')
          [Input('select_years', 'value')],)
def update_graph(select_years):
sales8=df.groupby(['Year'])['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
current_year = sales8[(sales8['Year'] == select_years)]['Sales'].sum()
sales9=df.groupby('Year')['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
sales9['PY']=sales9['Sales'].shift(1)
previous_year=sales9[(sales9['Year']==select_years)]['PY'].sum()




 return [

    html.H6(children='Current Year',id='text1',
            style={'textAlign': 'center',
                   'color': 'white'}),
    
    html.P('${0:,.2f}'.format(current_year),
           style={'textAlign': 'center',
                  'color': 'black',
                  'fontSize': 15,
                  'margin-top': '-10px'}),
     html.H6(children='Current Year',id='text2',
            style={'textAlign': 'center',
                   'color': 'white'}),
    
    html.P('${0:,.2f}'.format(previous_year),
           style={'textAlign': 'center',
                  'color': 'black',
                  'fontSize': 15,
                  'margin-top': '-10px'}),
    

]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a few errors in your code I think

1. if you have more than 1 output put them in a [] list
2. when you return your output need to have the same numbers of variables as in the output list (in your case 2 lists of HTML elements)

see the code below I didn't test it so I might miss something

```
html.Div([
        html.Div(id = 'text1'),
        html.Div(id = 'text2'),
        
        
    ],className='create_container2  three columns')



@app.callback([Output('text1', 'children'),
          Output('text2','children')],
          [Input('select_years', 'value')],)
def update_graph(select_years):
sales8=df.groupby(['Year'])['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
current_year = sales8[(sales8['Year'] == select_years)]['Sales'].sum()
sales9=df.groupby('Year')['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
sales9['PY']=sales9['Sales'].shift(1)
previous_year=sales9[(sales9['Year']==select_years)]['PY'].sum()




 return [ #text 1 children
    html.H6(children='Current Year',id='text1',
            style={'textAlign': 'center',
                   'color': 'white'}),
    html.P('${0:,.2f}'.format(current_year),
           style={'textAlign': 'center',
                  'color': 'black',
                  'fontSize': 15,
                  'margin-top': '-10px'})],
    [html.H6(children='Current Year',id='text2', #text 2 children 
            style={'textAlign': 'center',
                   'color': 'white'}),
    
    html.P('${0:,.2f}'.format(previous_year),
           style={'textAlign': 'center',
                  'color': 'black',
                  'fontSize': 15,
                  'margin-top': '-10px'}),
]
```